# Image won't display in ImageView (no such file or directory)

Tags: android

I am writing an app where the user taps on a button to create a digital signature.  Once done the user taps on save and the image is saved.  The folder does create and the image does save (I can browse to the folder on my phone and can see that it created it and saved the image)  However when trying to display the image it says that "no such fie or directory exists".

I have the correct permission to read and write to the external storage.

Here is the code:

```
String DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + 
"/DigitSign/";
String pic_name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", 
Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
String StoredPath = DIRECTORY + pic_name + ".png";


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
    verifyStoragePermissions(this);

    File folder = new 
    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DigitSign/");
    allFiles = folder.listFiles();

   .........

  btn_get_sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignatureButton);
    ImageView custsig = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.custimagesig);

    // Method to create Directory, if the Directory doesn't exists
    file = new File(DIRECTORY);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }
    if(file.exists()){

        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File image = new File(sd+DIRECTORY, StoredPath);
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
        custsig.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

    // Dialog Function
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    // Removing the features of Normal Dialogs
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signature);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    btn_get_sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},
                    null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.v("digiscan",
                                    "file " + path + " was scanned successfully: " + uri);
                        }
                    });

            dialog_action();

        }
    });
}
// Function for Digital Signature
public void dialog_action() {

    mContent = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mSignature = new signature(getApplicationContext(), null);
    mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    // Dynamically generating Layout through java code
    mContent.addView(mSignature, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mClear = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    mGetSign = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.getsign);
    mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
    mCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    view = mContent;

    mClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("tag", "Panel Cleared");
            mSignature.clear();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v("tag", "Panel Saved");
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mSignature.save(view, StoredPath);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Calling the same class
            recreate();
        }
    });
    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("tag", "Panel Cancelled");
            dialog.dismiss();
            // Calling the same class
            recreate();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

I honestly don't know why this is happening?
Can someone please assist me with this?

Comment: Have you checked the paths you're creating the `File`s with? Like this one: `new File(sd+DIRECTORY, StoredPath)`? What does `sd+DIRECTORY` end up as? Seems like it's not going to be what you want.

Comment: This is what I get:

Comment: E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/DigitSign/storage/emulated/0/DigitSign/20170604_073837.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Okay when i remove the sd+directory i get the following now: 
/storage/emulated/0/DigitSign/20170604_074215.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)  Which looks better.  but still won't display the image

Comment: OK, compare those filenames - `20170604_073837.png` and `20170604_074215.png`. Notice that it's changing each time. That's because each time you open the `Activity`, `pic_name` is recreated, and `new Date()` is going to be a different date/time.

Comment: Okay I understand that, but how do i display the image after i click saved and when I open the activity again it should then do the same for the new image?

Comment: I mean to display the new image in the ImageView after every time the activity starts again

Comment: Save the most recent pic name somewhere, like `SharedPreferences`.